# getting directory where file has been saved (tkinter filesave prompt)

Tags: python, user-interface, events, tkinter, volatile

I'm using `tkinter` to make a small GUI in python, part of which is to ask user where to save a file. 
Here is my code

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog as tf
import tkinter
import time

fileName = ""
def save():
    myFormats = [
    ('Text File','*.txt')
    ]
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    q = tf.asksaveasfilename(parent=root,filetypes=myFormats ,title="Save the image as...")
    print(type(q))
    fileName = q
    print(fileName)
    if len(fileName ) > 0:
        print ("Now saving under %s" % fileName)


master = Tk()
Button(master, text='Save file', command=save).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
print(fileName)

mainloop( )
print(fileName)
```

the `print(fileName)` inside `save()`, prints the proper path, but, the same statement at the end of the code just gives a , which it was initialized to in the beginning. I've been breaking my head trying to figure out why this is happening and finding a way to fix it. Any help would be wonderful!

Was wondering if it's something to do with volatile variables

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fileName` variable inside of `save` is different than the variable `fileName` in the global namespace due to scoping rules.  If you want to reference the global variable use the `global` keyword:

```
def save():
    myFormats = [('Text File','*.txt')]
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    q = tf.asksaveasfilename(parent=root,
            filetypes=myFormats,
            title="Save the image as...")
    global fileName
    fileName = q
```